# renderInContext image drawing with specified size

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, cgcontext

How to draw smaller image than size of context without using CGAffineTransform?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// center image
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, placement.origin.x, placement.origin.y);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:context];
```

The problem is that if `imageView.image.size` is bigger than `size` it will be drawn centered, but cut at borders (bigger image than drawing area). I want the image to fit, so would like to decrease size of `imageView.image.size`. Is there any way to achieve this using `renderInContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via `[imageView.layer renderInContext:context];` you can't change the size (or i didn't find a way). The only option to do so, is to create now image with drawImage (on requested size), allocate new UIImageView and draw its layer.

```
UIImage *resizedImage = [self createNewImageFrom:currentImage withSize:size];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:resizedImage];
// ...
[imageView.layer renderInContext:context];


- (UIImage*)createNewImageFrom:(UIImage*)image withSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height), image.CGImage);
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return outputImage;
}
```

Comment: Any comment for the downvote or just trolling around? If I'm doing something wrong it'd be good to inform what is it.

Comment: I am looking for some method to render layer to a different size, and finally I find the way, your answer may mislead other people similar to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this without transforming the context? It's the exact right tool for the job!

The simplest way here would be to call `CGContextScaleCTM` to apply a scale factor to the context.  That scale factor will effect all drawing to the context, including the call to `-renderIntoContext:`.

Comment: Because the context already is transformed and i need it to stay the same way as it is - using `saveCGState` n `Restore` will make problems too. Anyway i've found solution to my problem and described it here, will accept that answer tomorrow (can't earlier).

Comment: If `CGContextSaveGState`/`CGContextRestoreGState` aren't restoring the CTM of the context, then you're doing something else wrong. Your approach uses at least double the memory and will take at least twice as long to execute as transforming the context. Like I said: transforming the context is the *exact* right tool for the job.

Answer (score -1):

this is version for scaled size, just replace scale with size.width and size.height for any target size.

for UIView:

```
-(UIImage*)convertViewToImage:(UIView*)v withScale:(float)scale{
    //create bitmap context with scaled size
    CGSize s = v.bounds.size;
    s.width *= scale;
    s.height *= scale;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(s, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    //scale CTM to render and resotre CTM
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scale, scale);
    [v.layer renderInContext: context];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    UIImage*image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

for UIScrollView

```
-(UIImage*)convertScrollContentToImage:(UIScrollView*)sv withScale:(float)scale{
    //create bitmap context with scaled size
    CGSize s = sv.contentSize;
    s.width *= scale;
    s.height *= scale;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(s, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);


    {
        //set scroll.frame.size to contentSize, and contentOffset to 0
        CGPoint savedContentOffset = sv.contentOffset;
        CGRect savedFrame = sv.frame;

        sv.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        sv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sv.contentSize.width, sv.contentSize.height);

        //scale CTM to render and resotre CTM
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scale, scale);
        [sv.layer renderInContext: context];
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        //set scroll.frame.size and ContentOffset back
        sv.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
        sv.frame = savedFrame;

    }

    UIImage*image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: CGContextSaveGState is very memory consuming. I don't see any advantage of this code over mine, can you provide any comment?